# composition of binary relation equivalent to R,S symmetric

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, binary

I have to prove this: $R \circ S$ is symmetric $\iff R \circ S = S \circ R$. I tried to prove it, and I think I got the proof but I am not sure it is correct:
\begin{eqnarray*}
R \circ S \iff (\exists u)(x S u \land (u R y) \\
\iff (\exists u)(u S x \land y R u) \\
\iff (\exists u)(y R u \land u S x) \\
\iff (\exists u)(y R u \land y R y \land u S x \land x S x) \\
\iff (\exists u)( u R^{-1} \circ R y \land x S^{-1} \circ S u) \\
\iff (\exists u)( u R y \land x S u)\\
\iff (\exists u)( y R u \land u S x) \\
\iff y S \circ R x \\
\iff S \circ R
\end{eqnarray*} 
please tell me if this is okay, and should I also prove that $ S \circ R = R \circ S $ ?? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer I preassume that $R$ and $S$ are symmetric. You make use of that in your proof, but the extra condition is not mentioned in your question.

---

For a relation $T$ on a set $X$ the following statements are equivalent:

- $T$ is symmetric.
- $T\subseteq T^{-1}$.
- $T=T^{-1}$.

Next to that it can be shown that for relation $R,S$ on $X$ we have: $$(R\circ S)^{-1}=S^{-1}\circ R^{-1}$$

---

So if $R$ and $S$ are symmetric then $(R\circ S)^{-1}=S^{-1}\circ R^{-1}=S\circ R$

That means that the statement that $R\circ S$ is symmetric comes to the same as the statement that $S\circ R=R\circ S$.